# Hiding and displaying a menu using javascript in mvc

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using mvc in which I have two type of users; "student" and "staff". I want to filter these users and show a menu to them which, depending whether the user is a student or staff, should change. I'm trying to do this with Javascript.

**How do I accomplish this?**

This is what I already have:

```
<strong>STAFF USER</strong>

<div id="menucontainer">
    <ul id="menu">                  
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Staff Details", "StaffDetails", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Collection Master", "CollectionMaster", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Question Bank Master", "QuestionBankMaster", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Student Details", "StudentPersonnelDetails", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Answer Sheet", "Answersheet", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Exam Master", "ExamMaster", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Assign", "Assign", "Home")</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<strong>STUDENT USER</strong>

<div id="menucontainer1">
    <ul id="menu1">                  
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Student Details", "StudentPersonnelDetails", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Answer Sheet", "Answersheet", "Home")</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to hide it on client or server side?

Comment: Well, he said Javascript so... Edit: though I'd argue flagging it server side makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Straightforward example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function Foo()
  {
       if(@Roles.GetRolesForUser().Contains("Staff"))
       {
           document.getElementById('menucontainer').style.display = 'block';
           document.getElementById('menucontainer1').style.display = 'none';
       }
       else
       {
          document.getElementById('menucontainer').style.display = 'none';
          document.getElementById('menucontainer1').style.display = 'block';
       }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: And then call the function, or not have it in a function at all.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP is capable of calling a function

Comment: Me too. I just wanted to make it explicit in case someone didn't know. Sorry if I came across as rude. :)